# Jquery effects wait for previous to finish before running

Tags: jquery

I want three events to run after another so 1st line finishes then second line starts after that 3rd line start...so next element(effect) should wait until previous effect is finished?

Thanks

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
$('.login_menu_arrow.top').click(function(event)
{
    $("#login_menu").slideUp();
    $('.login_menu_arrow.top').hide();
    $('.login_menu_arrow.bottom').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

My test which won't work:

Source: [A way to chain a sequence of events in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730775/a-way-to-chain-a-sequence-of-events-in-jquery)

**1:**

```
$('.login_menu_arrow.top').click(function(event)
{
    $("#login_menu").slideUp(function() {
        $('.login_menu_arrow.top').hide(function() {
            $('.login_menu_arrow.bottom').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Source: [How do you get JQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)

**2:**

```
$('.login_menu_arrow.top').click(function(event)
{
    $(this).queue(function() {
        $("#login_menu").slideUp();
        $(this).dequeue();
    }).queue(function() {
        $('.login_menu_arrow.top').hide();
        $(this).dequeue();
    }).queue(function() {
        $('.login_menu_arrow.bottom').show();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with #1, but [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) isn't an animation effect [unless you call it with a duration](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete), so you don't use a callback with it:

```
$('.login_menu_arrow.top').click(function(event)
{
    $("#login_menu").slideUp(function() {
        $('.login_menu_arrow.top').hide();
        $('.login_menu_arrow.bottom').show();
    });
});
```

Note that this works because you're animating a single element (`#login_menu`). If you were animating multiple elements, you'd get multiple calls to the callback (one call per element as it completed). If you were animating multiple elements and wanted a single callback when they were all done, you'd use `promise` after starting the animation, [as shown in this example](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1). But you don't need to do that since you're animating a single element.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into `.promise()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Set duration to `hide()` method to animate it:

```
$('.login_menu_arrow.top').click(function(event)
{
    $("#login_menu").slideUp(function() {
        $('.login_menu_arrow.top').hide(400,function() {
            $('.login_menu_arrow.bottom').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Or you could use `fadeOut()` method.